# How to specify CosmosDb Synapse Link types when parquet type is incorrect?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-synapse

I have a CosmosDb and a Synapse workspace linked. Everything almost works using Synapse to create SQL views to the Cosmos data.

In Cosmos I have one data set with a property that is always a zero. I know it is actually a decimal because it is a price and future data is likely to contain decimal prices.

In Synapse I need to project this data into an SQL view where that column is correctly a decimal(19,4).

When I run an OpenRowSet query into the Cosmos data and attempt to specify the type for this property I get the following error.

```
select *
from OPENROWSET(
    'CosmosDb',
    'account=myaccount;database=myDatabase;region=theRegion;key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    [myCollection])
    with (
    [salesPrice] float '$.salesPrice')
as testQuery
```

I get the error:

```
Column 'salesPrice' of type 'FLOAT' is not compatible with external data type 'Parquet physical type: INT64', please try with 'BIGINT'.
```

Obviously a BIGINT here is going to fail as soon as I get a true decimal price.

I think the parquet type is getting set to `BIGINT` because in Cosmos all the values for this column are zero. I guess more generally it would be the same problem if the Cosmos property was all non-zero integers.

How can I force the type of salesPrice to be a decimal or float?

(I don't want to get side tracked here on float vs decimal for monetary values, I understand the difference; this error happens either way)

### UPDATE

This problem manifests itself also in another way without specifying a schema with `OPENROWSET`.

In a new CosmosDb collection insert a document such as:

```
{
   "myid" : 1,
   "price" : 0
}
```

If I wait a minute or so I can query this document from Synapse with:

```
select *
from OPENROWSET(
    'myCosmosDb',
    'account=myAccount;database=myDatabase;region=myRegion;key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    [myCollection])
    as testQuery;
```

and I get the expected results.

Now add a second document:

```
{
   "myid" : 1,
   "price" : 1.1
}
```

and re-run the query and I get the same error:

```
Column 'price' of type 'FLOAT' is not compatible with external data type 'Parquet physical type: INT64', please try with 'BIGINT'
```

Is there any way to work around or prevent these kinds of errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about set the document like

```
{
   "myid" : "1",
   "price" : "1.1"
}
```

Comment: The data doesn't come from source systems as strings. I suppose it we could change all data going into cosmos to strings but it doesn't feel very satisfactory solution, neither does seeding the collection in cosmos with explicit types.

The problem also would show up if data models feeding into CosmosDb changed and I wanted to edit the parquet schema to reflect the change. Right now I have to drop the entire collection after backing up the data, reload and rebuild in Synapse.

I have a support call out with Azure on this but not very hopeful.

Comment: Hope you solve it soon. Anyway, I still think that changing the data in string format is the most convenient way.

Comment: Long time returning to this, but eventually we went with transforming all json data to strings and then casting back in Synapse the correct data types.  So finally accepted! Oddly enough a similar issue came up with a requirement to convert json to csv. Given that json doesn't have to present all properties all time (whereas csv does) there can easily be mismatches if the csv results need to be merged into existing csv files. More than that we needed to break out nested arrays into separate csv files. All this requires some kind of schema to enable this.