# Importing JSON from CosmosDB via Synapse to SQL

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-synapse

I'm trying to make (simple, no deep nesting) JSON data that's in CosmosDB NoSQL analytical store available for a colleague in Synapse SQL Serverless Pool.

My first attempt involved building Views on the CosmosDB Linked Service in Azure Data Studio. At first, this seemed to work, however, for two tables I'm getting errors:

```
Column 'xxx' of type 'FLOAT' is not compatible with external data type 'Parquet physical type: INT64', please try with 'BIGINT'.
```

The weird thing is that the column contains integers only, and in the view the datatype is specified as bigint.
I found a post describing a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65419050/how-to-specify-cosmosdb-synapse-link-types-when-parquet-type-is-incorrect).

Then I thought it might be easier to just use the "Copy" pipeline tool in Synapse, using the CosmosDB as the source, and write the data to a Parquet sink.
However, now I'm running into issues that some of the properties are arrays, I found the option to change the incoming type to array with "add array". But when I then run the pipeline I get the following error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=JsonUnsupportedHierarchicalComplexValue,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The retrieved type of data JArray is not supported yet. Please either remove the targeted column 'xxx' or enable skip incompatible row to skip the issue rows.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "xxxx",
    "details": []
}
```

I have a strong feeling that I'm overlooking something simple to make this possible. It cannot be this complex right?
I'd appreciate any tips and help to make the data available!

Comment: can you share sample data that you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue and faced similar error as you.

[image]

As the error is clearly saying that to remove the target column or skip incompatible row. The cause of error is because your input Json object is contained Array. And array data type is not supported for synapse SQL.

- To resolve this issue, you need to check **Map complex values to string** option under `Mapping` as below.

[image]

Or if you want to expand that array into different column you have to use `data flow`

Comment: Hi Pratik! This is indeed what I ended up doing and it works for us. Thanks